# Pearlmutter's method for Hessian multiplication

Tags: gradient, hessian

I am trying to understand the abstract below from [Pearlmutter's paper](http://www.bcl.hamilton.ie/~barak/papers/nc-hessian.pdf).

Can someone clarify to me why $R_{\bf{v}}\{\bf{w}\}=\bf{v}$? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of obvious, here:

$$\mathcal{R}_\mathrm{\textbf{v}}(\mathrm{\textbf{w}})\equiv (\partial/\partial r) (\mathrm{\textbf{w}}+r\mathrm{\textbf{v}})=\mathrm{\textbf{v}}$$